# Convert values of utilization category from AC7a / AC7b to AC5a / AC5b - Is it possible to estimate?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical

I have a contactor which is rated at 440V and 25 A for utilization category AC7a and 8.5 A for AC7b. Is it possible to give an estimate about the maximum current and power usage for appliances of categories AC5a / AC5b?

Comment: Cross posted here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/214928/97780

Comment: I deleted the question on diy stack exchange

Comment: So next place to post will be the electrical stack?

Comment: @SolarMike It's off-topic on electrical engineering..Already posted there

Comment: So what makes it on topic here? Perhaps it is off topic wherever...

Comment: After reading https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I cannot see why it should be off-topic..But I let moderators decide..

Comment: weird. might be too general. Some of the regulars at EE have answered similar questions in the past.